# Catel Application with log4net libraries

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, log4net, catel

I have written a simple Catel MVVM WPF application.  I am trying to use some libraries previously written that use Log4Net for logging as there is a LOT of code and it is shared with non-Catel based apps.

Anytime a call is made to a library that calls the Log4Net log calls (Debug,Info,Error and so on) the application crashes.

Is there any easy way to support this mixed usage scenario? I have a log4net listener based upon the documentation, but I am not really sure how to completely integrate it. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: "the application crashes" with no information about the exception that caused it to crash is pretty much unanswerable.  Unhandled exceptions get logged in the Event Viewer.  Copy the text out of the logs and paste it into an [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Log4net listeners only work if you actually log via Catel. So this mixed situation will work when:

- "Legacy" parts log via log4net
- New parts log via Catel

Then Catel can forward the logs and log4net can still take care of the logging for you. In that case, you can simple create a LogListener and register it in the Catel.LogManager class. In your log listener you can forward the log messages to log4net.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the response.